# How Install "Telepathy Connection Manager"

Tags: instant-messaging, telegram, kde-telepathy, office365

When I want to configure **instants messaging**, for some applications like *Office365 lync* and *Telegram*, I receive this error:

```
This IM Account cannot be created - 
a Telepathy Connection Manager named 'morse' is missing or 
it cannot handle protocol 'telegram'. 
Please try installing morse with your package manager.
```

Comment: after running `git clone git://anongit.kde.org/telepathy-morse` , how can I install it?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently a [confirmed bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ktp-contact-list/+bug/1512135) about this not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Someone packaged telepathy-morse for xenial, yakkety and zesty. It is in my PPA - https://launchpad.net/~clivejo/+archive/ubuntu/telepathy-morse

I would appreciate anyone who is wanting to test this feature to install it and try it out.

A couple of issues I have noticed are:

- You need to give the full international telephone number.
- You need to go Offline and then Online a few times in Telepathy for it to actually send you the code and be able to log into your account.

Any issues with this code can be reported upstream at the following URL:

https://github.com/TelepathyIM/telepathy-morse

Comment: The ppa doesn't seem to exist anymore.